# PatternSyntaxException being thrown with String.matches()?

Tags: java, regex, exception

I'm writing an assembler program that analyzes assembly code and generates object code. However, I'm having some issues with one of the regex functions. I have had no experience with java regular expressions, so I'm not quite sure what I am doing to cause this exception. Below is the function that is throwing the exception. THe first operand being evaluated is "0", which should of course evaluate to false.

```
//Returns true if operand is a Symbol, false otherwise.
public boolean isSymbol(String operand){
    if(!operand.equals("")){
        if(((operand.matches("[a-zA-Z]*"))&&
                (!operand.matches(".'"))) ||(operand.matches("*"))){ //Exception
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: meant to be a literal "'". So for example, it would match C'50', or K'0', etc. Am I writing this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

i think your problem is the `*` expression. `*` in java regexpx is nto meaningful on its own, it has to follow something else (it means "zero or more times").
if you want the literal `*` you'll need to escape it - `\\*`
here's the javadoc for Pattern, which lists your options http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still a bit confused with your explanation

Comment: in `operand.matches("*")` - are you trying to ask if operand is the literal string `*` or something else?

Comment: i think kori put it better than me below

Answer (score 1):

```
operand.matches("*")
```

matches takes a String representation of a regular expression, and '*' is not a valid regular expression.  For the long regular expression intro, you can look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

In a regular expression, the '*' character means "match the previous thing 0 or more times".  For example:

```
"a".matches("a*")        // is true
"aaaaaaa".matches("a*")  // is true
"aaaaaab".matches("a*b") // is true
```

If you want to match a literal '*' character in your input string, you will have to escape the '*' in the regular expression like this:

```
operand.matches("\\*")
```

then

```
"a*".matches("a\\*")       // is true
"*".matches("\\*")         // is true
"aaaa*b".matches("a*\\*b") // is true
"0".matches("\\*")         // is false, which I think is what you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing if condition as below :

```
if(((operand.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) && !operand.matches(".'")))){`enter code here`
```

Here + means 1 or more, which makes sure that oprand has at least one a-z or A-Z in it.